# How can I ask the user to enter an integer or char with one question?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, structure

I am making a grocerys store interface for a school project. First there is a menu that asks the user if they want to S-shop or Q-quit, if they choose S a menu showing products pops up with the price per lb. the user can then choose a product by entering a number 1-7 and then choosing how many lb of that product they want. my problem is that after this Im supposed to ask the user to make a selection, the selection can be another product so a number from 1-7, or they can enter options from a new menu being T- transaction complete or X- cancel transaction. the way I have set up my code is that I can only accept an integer when asking the user to make another selection. I have been only coding for about a month so any guidance will be a big help.

````
#include <iostream>             
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>               
#include <cstdlib>              
#include <fstream>               
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct Transaction
{
    string item;
    float price;
    
    
    //derived variables
    float subTotal;
    float totalSales;
    
    
    
};

// Decleration of prototype 
void projectStart();
void projectEnd();
int getIntegerData(string);
float getFloatData(string);
char getCharData(string);
string getStringData(string);
void mainMenu();
void loadFile(int&, Transaction []);
void transactionShopping(int, Transaction[]);
void subMenu();
void performCalculation(int, Transaction[]);

int main()
{
    // Displays start of project 
    projectStart();
    cout << fixed <<setprecision(2);
    
    //declared variables
    Transaction myPurchase[25];
    int itemSize;
    itemSize = 0;
    
    loadFile(itemSize, myPurchase);
    
    transactionShopping(itemSize, myPurchase);
    performCalculation(itemSize, myPurchase);
    
    
    
    // Displays end of project
    projectEnd();
    
    return 0;
    
}// end of main
void performCalculation(int itemSize, Transaction myPurchase[])
{
    float salesTax = .0825;
    float subTotal = 0;
    
    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < itemSize; ctr++)
    {
        subTotal = subTotal + myPurchase[ctr].subTotal;
    }
}
void transactionShopping(int itemSize, Transaction myPurchase[])
{ // start of transactionShopping(int itemSize, Transaction myPurchase[])

    //declared variables
    string dashes(40, '-');
    char selection;
    int itemSelection;
    float itemWeight;
    float cost;

    mainMenu();
    selection = getCharData("\tMake your selection: ");
    while(true)
    { // start of while(true)

        if (selection == 'X')
        {   
            cout << "!!! Transaction Cancelled" << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {   if (selection == 'S')
            {//start of if (selection == 'S')   
                cout << dashes << endl;
                cout << "\tHernandez Grocery Store" << endl;
                cout << dashes << endl;
                cout << "Shopping" << endl;
                for (int ctr = 0; ctr < itemSize; ctr++ )
                { //start of for loop
                    cout << ctr + 1 << " "<< myPurchase[ctr].item << " " << myPurchase[ctr].price << endl;
                } //end of for loop
                subMenu();
                itemSelection = getIntegerData("\tMake your selection: ");
    
                
                if (itemSelection >= 1 && itemSelection <= itemSize)
                { //start of if loop
                    itemWeight = getFloatData("\tEnter pounds of " + myPurchase[itemSelection -1].item + ": ");
                    
                    if (itemWeight > 0)
                    { //start of itemweight loop
                        cost = itemWeight * myPurchase[itemSelection -1].price;
                        cout << "\tCost: " << itemWeight << " lbs" << " of " << myPurchase[itemSelection -1].item << ": $" << cost << endl;
                    } // end of itemweight loop
                    else
                    { //start of else
                        cout << "ERROR Message. Enter a valid weight" << endl;
                    } //end of else
            }
            else if (selection == 'T')  
            {
                cout << "Grocery List" << endl;
                cout << "myPurchase[itemSelection -1].item" << endl;
            }
            }
        
        }
        
    }
} // end of transactionShopping(int itemSize, Transaction myPurchase[])


// menu function
void subMenu()
{ //start of subMenu
    string dashes(40, '-');
    cout << dashes << endl;
    cout << "T Complete Transaction" << endl;
    cout << "X Cancel Transaction" << endl;
    
    
} //end of subMenu
void mainMenu()
{ //start of mainMenu
    string dashes(40, '-');
    cout << dashes << endl;
    cout << "Hernandez Grocery store" << endl;
    cout << dashes << endl;
    cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "\tS Shop" << endl;
    cout << "\tQ Quit" << endl;
    cout << dashes << endl;
} //end of mainMenu
//function will load the file
void loadFile(int & itemSize, Transaction myPurchase[])
{ //start of void loadFile(int & itemSize, Transaction myPurchase[])
    ifstream menuFile("menu.txt");
    string item;
    float price;
    itemSize = 0;
    
    if (menuFile)
    { //if (menuFile)
        while (menuFile >> item >> price)
        { // start of while (menuFile >> item >> price)
            
            myPurchase[itemSize].item = item;
            myPurchase[itemSize].price = price;
            itemSize = itemSize + 1;

            
            if (itemSize == 25)
            { 
                break;
            } 
        } //while while (menuFile >> item >> price)
    menuFile.close();
    }// if (menuFile)
    else
    {
        cout << "File does not exist" << endl;
        
    }

} //end of void loadFile(int & itemSize, Transaction myPurchase[])

char getCharData(string prompt)
{ //start of getCharData
    char value;
    while (true)
    { //start of while(true)
            cout << prompt;
            cin >> value;
            
            cin.clear(); //clears the cin
            cin.ignore(120, '\n'); //clears up to 120 characters or until enter button is hit
            
    
            value = toupper(value);
            if (value == 'S' || value == 'Q' || value == 'T' || value =='X')
            {
                return value;
            }
        cout << "\t\tError Message Invalid Selection" << endl;
    }
} //end of getCharData

// This function will get a float value from the user
float getFloatData(string prompt)
{
    float value;
    
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        while (!(cin >> value))
        {
            cout << "\t\tError Message. Non numeric is entered"  << endl;
            cin.clear(); 
            cin.ignore(120, '\n');  
            cout << prompt;
        } 
            
        if (value >= 1 && value <= 10)
        {
            return value;   
        } 
            
        cout << "\t\tError Message. ONLY integers between 1 and 10"  << endl;
    } 
} 

// This function will get an integer value from the user
int getIntegerData(string prompt)
{
    int value;
    
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        while (!(cin >> value))
        {
            cout << "\t\t\tError Message. Non numeric is entered"  << endl;
            cin.clear(); // clear error buffer
            cin.ignore(120, '\n');  // c;lear upto 120 chars or it reaches an enter
            cout << prompt;
        } //    while (!(cin >> value))
        if (value >= 1 && value <= 7)
        {
            return value;
        }
        cout << "Enter from provided options 1-7" << endl;
        
            
    } // end of while (true)
} // end of int getIntegerData()

// This function will return a string data entered by users
string getStringData(string prompt)
{
    string value;
    cout << prompt;
    getline(cin, value, '\n'); // accepts spaces in the entry
    
    return value;
    
} // end of int getStringData(string prompt)

// The function will display the start of the project 
void projectStart()
{
    cout << "-----------------------------"  << endl;
    cout << "Project " << endl;

    cout << "Objectives" << endl;
    cout << "\tUser can nagivate our product list and pick the product and amount they would like" << endl;
    cout << "\tThe user will receive a total price at the end or exit if they choose to cancel " << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------"  << endl;
} // end of projectStart()

// The function will display the end of the project 
void projectEnd()
{
    cout << "-----------------------------"  << endl;
    cout << "End of Project" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------"  << endl;
} // end of projectEnd()```



I tried replacing my itemSelection = getIntegerData("\tMake your selection: "); with getCharData but not sure if this can even work since i would have to change my getchardata function to check for integers would entering them as '1' work?
````

Comment: This is way too much code, considering your intention to ask how to ask for a digit or a letter... Please, review how to write a [mcve].

Comment: _the way I have set up my code is that I can only accept an integer when asking the user to make another selection_ Then, this might be the wrong way. Why not [this way](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61f1f0d3e9a3e380)?

Comment: Read the line entered as a `std::string`.  Look at the contents of the string and decide what to do.

Comment: Users don't enter integers or chars; they enter **text**. It's up to your program to sort out whether the text can be converted to the type that it needs. Stream extractors (`>>`) do that, with a different extractor for each different type. If you want to convert to different types depending on what the input text is you have to read the text and figure it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in a character, ie. `char input; std::cin >> input`. If the character is a digit `input >= '0' && input <= '9'`, you can parse it as an integer `input - '0'`, otherwise you can parse it as a character.